# Java: One int Array of Differences

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of x and y coordinates that I pass to a method where it checks for first differences.  My problem when I return it my program only displays the first difference of those first two coordinates.

```
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ardDifference));
        fin.close();
    }

    public static double Difference(double ardY[]) {
        double ardDifference[] = new double[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ardDifference[i] = ardY[i + 1] - ardY[i];
            return ardDifference[i];
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're returning a `double` which means a single value. Probably you're looking to return a `double[]` or, even better, a `List<BigDecimal>`

Comment: Question is not clear. What do you want to do in the method Difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to not be returning the entire array, you should change to

```
// Return type  \/    is double[] instead of double
public static double[] Difference(double ardY[]) {
    double ardDifference[] = new double[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ardDifference[i] = ardY[i + 1] - ardY[i];
    }
    return ardDifference;//Returns entire array
}
```

You are currently only returning one double, not the entire array

Answer (score 0):

Because you are having a return in the loop it returns during first iteration itself.
I feel you don't need a loop here.Or if you need multiple differences then change the return type to `double[]` and return `ardDifference`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ardDifference[i] = ardY[i + 1] - ardY[i];
    }
            return ardDifference;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//modify public static double Difference(double ardY[]) { 
public static double[] Difference(double ardY[]) {
    double ardDifference[] = new double[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ardDifference[i] = ardY[i + 1] - ardY[i];  
        // remove this line return ardDifference[i];       
    }
    //modify return 0;
    return ardDifference;
}
```

You are currently only returning one double, not the entire array